# Hyperref not linking ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am having an issue with hyperref not linking the ToC to the chapters/sections. I have had a look around and I can not find a solution to my problem. If this is duplicated, my apologies...

I am writing my thesis at the moment and its due soon so I'd like this fixed.

I am currently using TexLive2013 in Ubuntu 12.04. I was previously using TexLive2009 however, I read that the caption package can cause hyperref to stop early so I updated. I am still having this issue with the folowwing error:

```
Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
```

Is this driver needed? Can I just delete it?

Either way, hyperref appears to be working fine elsewhere i.e. urls etc. I have pasted my preamble below, perhaps I have a package conflict? The update to TexLive2013 however did cause the lineno package to stop working

Any advice appreciated.

Cheers,
Dave

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{/home/dbyrne/PHD/Dropbox/MyThesis/report_custom}
\usepackage[innermargin=40mm, outermargin=20mm]{geometry}



\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} %for image placement
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[authoryear, square]{natbib}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
% \usepackage[]{lineno} % for line numbers. Not working with Texlive2013
\usepackage{acronym}



\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,implicit=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all,
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=CadetBlue,
    filecolor=CadetBlue,
    linkcolor=CadetBlue,
    urlcolor=CadetBlue
}


\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\graphicspath{paths}
\linespread{1.3} %1=single, 1.3=1.5 and 1.6=double

\begin{document}
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

As DG pointed out below, the issue is with loading hyperref with the [implicit=false] option. Once removed, the ToC was linked. Thanks again DG.

For those wondering why I loaded [implicit=false] in the first place; I can not remember. Google probably told me at some stage..

Comment: The option `implicit=false` for hyperref is responsible for this behavior. It would be nice if you could explain, why you have set it to `false`, because all the packages used in your example seem to be compatible with hyperref.

Comment: There’s no need to add “SOLVED” to the title. A question is marked as solved by accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On TL2013 I was able to successfully compile the following document with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report} 
\usepackage[innermargin=40mm, outermargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} %for image placement
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[authoryear, square]{natbib}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all,
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=CadetBlue,
    filecolor=CadetBlue,
    linkcolor=CadetBlue,
    urlcolor=CadetBlue;
}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\graphicspath{paths}
\linespread{1.3} %1=single, 1.3=1.5 and 1.6=double

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Principles of Reason}

\begin{linenumbers}
\kant[1-2]
\end{linenumbers}

\chapter{Things in themselves}

\begin{linenumbers}
\kant[3-4]
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

I encountered non of the problems you described. As I only changed three things (I used the document class `report`, added `use names,dvipsnames`to `\usepackage{color}`, and deleted the option `implicit=false` from `\usepackage{hyperref}`), I do suspect that the source of your problems is either your TL installation or your custom document class.

As a first step I would try to compile your document using the class `report` and compare the errors.

Comment: Hi DG. Thanks for your efforts and help. You are correct, having the [implicit=false] is what cause the problem. I can not remember why I included this option, it was a fix to some problem I was having at some stage.