# Hyperlinks from chapter and section headings back to the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, links

What I'd finally like to have are clickable backlinks from the headings to the table of contents. The goal is to click on a heading and land on that exact heading in the toc. As far as my search efforts are concerned there is no easy way to reach this. So I tried to start by linking to the toc like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163961/reference-to-the-table-of-contents-page). But I already fail to place links in headings, which seems to be impossible and results in this error message:

```
pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode.
```

Just to clarify this, as there seem to be potential misunderstandings in other discussions on the web: I don't want to change the style of the headings! The links should be invisible like when using the `hidelinks` option. I left the links visible in the MWE for better overview.

So here's the MWE with one of my error producing lines NOT commented out:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Works like a charm

% And I would like to do something like that too:
% \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\hyperlink{toc}{\chapter{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{toc}{\tableofcontents}

\chapter{This is a great headline}%Working
% \chapter{This \hyperlink{toc}{is} a great headline}%Not working
% \chapter{\hyperlink{toc}{This is a great headline}}%Also not working
\hyperlink{toc}{\chapter{This is a great headline}}%Also not working
Here is some text to prove, that \hyperlink{toc}{links} to toc work, if they're not in headings\ldots
\section{This is a section heading}
% \section{This is a \hyperlink{toc}{section} heading}%Also not working
\section{and another}

\chapter{This is a bad headline!}
\section{last section}

\end{document}
```

In the end it would be great to get the links automatically in every heading, like I tried to with the `renewcommand`.

Comment: The main problem is that the chapter title (even the optional chapter title) is used in more than one place.  I can put a \hypertarget into the TOC, but it will also be placed on the top of each page.  What you really need is to modify \contentsline to add a hypertaget such as backlink.chapter.1 (where chapter.1 is the current 4th argument).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I placed the redefinition of `\contentsline` after `\begin{document}` since hyperref puts what appears to be a redefinition in the aux file.  But on closer examination it seems this code doesn't actually do anything.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\hyperchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\@ifstar\starchapter\mychapter}
\def\starchapter{\hyperchapter*}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2][\@empty]% #1=optional (toc and top of page), #2=title
{\ifx#1\@empty \hyperchapter[#2]{\hyperlink{toc.chapter.\thechapter}{#2}}
 \else \hyperchapter[#1]{\hyperlink{toc.chapter.\thechapter}{#2}}
 \fi}

\let\hypersection\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\starsection\mysection}
\def\starsection{\hypersection*}
\newcommand{\mysection}[2][\@empty]% #1=optional (toc), #2=title
{\ifx#1\@empty \hypersection[#2]{\hyperlink{toc.section.\thesection}{#2}}
 \else \hypersecton[#1]{\hyperlink{toc.section.\thesection}{#2}}
 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\let\hypercontentsline=\contentsline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\hypertarget{toc.#4}{}\hypercontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is a great headline}
\section{and another}

\chapter{This is a bad headline!}
\section{last section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, if I could click on "accept this answer a 2nd time" I would do it... :) Solved everything. Thanks very much!

Comment: I have a habit of refining my answers until I get it right.  For example, I just noticed that there is a \chapter* and \section* option I need to implement.

Comment: I wish you good luck :) In the meantime I found out that a `\let\chapter=\section` after all of this has to be `\let\hyperchapter=\hypersection` to work....

Comment: :D You're pretty fast. On the first sight I'd say there's a `\makeatother` missing...

Comment: I caught it.  Also used \@empty instead of \empty.  I generally don't bother, but since I need \@ifstar anyway...

Comment: ...and I checked if you can put the contentsline stuff into the preamble and it seems to work if i put it before the other stuff!

Comment: Figured out this be done to also make **subsections** and **subsubsections** clickable by just changing every time we see the word "section" in the bottom command to "subsection".

Comment: Is there anyway to also make the **section-numbers** clickable? The section-numbers in my table of contents are clickable, and the discrepancy bugs me.

Comment: @LukeDavis - See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126994/hyperref-not-linking-toc `\hypersetup{linktoc=all}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry to be clear, the *section-numbers and section-text* in my Table of Contents are clickable, whereas *only the section-text* where they appear in the document are clickable -- e.g. for the section header "1 MySection", I can only click on the "MySection" part. I was hoping to make the section-numbers where they appear in the document to also be clickable.

Comment: I tried putting the entire \chapter inside the target, but you cannot start or end a target in vmode.  The changes I made to the title were superficial.  What you want is much more invasive, and will depend on the definition of \chapter (which is document class dependent).

Comment: @LukeDavis - In other words, it can be done, but it would be best to ask a new question using your specific document class.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, I may do so. Alternatively, is there a simpler way to make the *table-of-contents text, but not the section numbers* clickable? Just wanted the numbers to either always be clickable or always not. Obviously this is a very nitpicky thing.

Comment: @LukeDavis - One could modify \contentsline to NOT start the link, then modify \numberline to start it instead.  Again, that is really outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, I started a question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412773/73149).

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657250/63743) if you are interested to extend this to the chapters in the appendix.

Comment: I had issues with the ToC breaking across odd places across a page when using `\documentclass[report]` and I had to change it to what's in the answer above `\documentclass{scrreprt}`.

Comment: There is LaTeX and there is KOMA.  They have very little in common.  (Beamer is worse.)  Actually, a LaTeX solution may be easier.