# How can I make the section-text in a Table of Contents clickable, but keep the section-number *unclickable*?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, hyperlink

I recently found [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251964/73149) on how to make section titles clickable/return to their entry in the Table of Contents -- only problem is, the **title text** of the section headers are clickable, but the **numbers** are not. I simply want to make the Table of Contents mirror this style.

Here is a template document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,footskip=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    linktoc=all,
}

% For clickable section headers
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251964/73149
\makeatletter
\let\hypersection\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\starsection\mysection}
\def\starsection{\hypersection*}
\newcommand{\mysection}[2][\@empty]% #1=optional (toc), #2=title
{\ifx#1\@empty \hypersection[#2]{\hyperlink{toc.section.\thesection}{#2}}
 \else \hypersection[#1]{\hyperlink{toc.section.\thesection}{#2}}
 \fi}
\let\hypersubsection\subsection
\def\subsection{\@ifstar\starsubsection\mysubsection}
\def\starsubsection{\hypersubsection*}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[2][\@empty]% #1=optional (toc), #2=title
{\ifx#1\@empty \hypersubsection[#2]{\hyperlink{toc.subsection.\thesubsection}{#2}}
 \else \hypersubsection[#1]{\hyperlink{toc.subsection.\thesubsection}{#2}}
 \fi}
\makeatother
\let\hypercontentsline=\contentsline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\hypertarget{toc.#4}{}\hypercontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% Body
\begin{document}
  \title{This is a Title}
  \date{}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \section{A Section}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \section{Another One}
  \subsection{Hello}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \subsection{Goodbye}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \section{Final Section}
  Peace out.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not mirror the other way?

Comment: Got the impression that would be more difficult. Check out the comment thread in the answer from the thread I linked.

Comment: One involves trying to separate \numberline from the title, the other involves replacing \@sect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This both adds the section number to the back link, and removes the section number from the toc line.  The latter was definitely harder.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,footskip=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    linktoc=all,
}

% For clickable section headers
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251964/73149
\makeatletter
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{\sbox0{\@svsec}% measure width
      \interlinepenalty \@M
      \hangindent=\dimexpr \wd0+#3\relax
      \noindent\hskip #3\relax
      \hyperlink{toc.#1.\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        {\@svsec #8}%
      \@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
      \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
      \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

%\let\hypercontentsline=\contentsline
%\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\hypertarget{toc.#4}{}\hypercontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% begin code to remove section numbers from the TOC
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@savenumber}{}% reserve global names
\newcommand{\@gettitle}[1]% remove \numberline from title
  {\bgroup\let\numberline=\@gobble#1\egroup}

\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{% #1=type, #2=entry, #3=page, #4=anchor
  \hypertarget{toc.#4}{}% set up backlink
  \bgroup% separate \numberline from title
    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\gdef\@savenumber{##1}}%
    \sbox0{#2}% throw away title, keep number
  \egroup
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
  }\x
  \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifcase\Hy@linktoc % none
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
    \or % section
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{\numberline{\@savenumber}%
        {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}\@gettitle{#2}\hyper@linkend}}{#3}%
    \or % page
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{{#2}}{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \else % all
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{\numberline{\@savenumber}%
          {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}\@gettitle{#2}\hyper@linkend}
        \egroup}{}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{\numberline{\@savenumber}%
          {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}\@gettitle{#2}\hyper@linkend}
        }{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Body
\begin{document}
  \title{This is a Title}
  \date{}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \section{A Section}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \section{Another One}
  \subsection{Hello}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \subsection{Goodbye}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \section{Final Section}
  Peace out.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is utterly black magic to me. Might want to mention also that the `\let\hypercontentsline` seems to make the backlinks point to specific items in the Table of Contents; they point to the head of the document without those lines. At least this is the case when I tried it.

Comment: It worked for me.  Both redefinitions of \contentsline add \hypertarget{toc.#4}{} at the start.  The source for \@sect comes from source2e.pdf (CTAN) and the source for \contentsline comes from hyperref.sty.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for \chapters :(

Comment: @Svalorzen - Macros like \@sect are specific to sections.