# Reference From Titles back to the Table of Contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, back-referencing

It is possible to click on the TOC to a subsection.
I saw in a book that when you then lick on the title of the subsection, you went back to the TOC page.
Is this possible to create this programmatically and nor wrap the title with a link to the TOC

Comment: Does one lick or click on a title? :-)

Comment: As provided by Marijn
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251904/hyperlinks-from-chapter-and-section-headings-back-to-the-table-of-contents